# How to configure my bib-style with XeLatex?

Tags: bibliographies, xetex

Here is an example of my problem

```
\documentclass[doctor,language=english]{thesis}
...
\bibliography{bib/mybib}
\bibliographystyle{unsrt}
...
\end{document}
```

And for a bib-entry as

```
@article{Marcastel:1621583,
      author        = "Marcastel, Fabienne",
      title         = "{CERN's Accelerator Complex. La chaine des
                       acc\'el\'erateurs du CERN}",
      month         = "Oct",
      year          = "2013",
      reportNumber  = "OPEN-PHO-CHART-2013-001",
      url           = "https://cds.cern.ch/record/1621583",
      note          = "General Photo",
}
```

The reference style of my pdf output is looking like this:
[image: The bib-style what I got]

But What I expected style is like this:
[image: The bib-style what I expected]

The XeLatex seems not used the correct bibstyle I defined, how I can do with that?

Comment: The output you show is indeed not what `unsrt` would produce. Check that you only have one `\bibliographystyle` in your document. Also check that your `thesis` class does not hard-code a different style. Have a look at the `.blg` file (BibTeX's log) to see if it complains about several `\bibstyle`s: `Illegal, another \bibstyle command`.

Comment: Hi @moewe, you are right, I have checked the `blg` file, and found the `bibstyle` is overridden in the `thesis` class, thank you.